# Elasticsearch spark reading slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

Reading from Elasticsearch `v6.2` into spark using the prescribed spark connector `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:6.3.2` is horrendously slow. This is from a 3 node ES cluster with index:

```
curl https://server/_cat/indices?v
green  open   db MmVwAwYfTz4eE_L-tncbwQ   5   1  199983131      9974871    105.1gb         51.8gb
```

Reading on a (10 node, 1tb mem, >50 VCPUs) spark cluster:

```
val query = """{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}"""

val df = spark.read
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes","server")
  .option("es.port", "443")
  .option("es.net.ssl","true")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.input.use.sliced.partitions", "false")
  .option("es.scroll.size", "1000")
  .option("es.read.field.include", "f1,f2,f3")
  .option("es.query",query)
  .load("db")

df.take(1)
```

That took 10 minutes to execute.
[image]

Is this how (slowly) it's supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi @ixaxaar, did you find the reason or any solution?

Comment: Nope, could not really figure it out. Tried various settings and configs including `es.input.use.sliced.partition`, finally went ahead with dumping the whole index into s3 (https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) and then loading in spark.

Comment: Try to check CPU utilization with `https://server/_cat/nodes?v&h=id,cpu&s=id`

Answer (score 1):

This is not how slow it is supposed to be, and the answer could be found in the screenshot you shared:

The column `Stages: Succeeded/Total` in Spark UI shows only one task that runs the read operation, I don't think that this is what you would expect, otherwise, what's the point of having a whole cluster.

I have faced the same problem and it took me a while to figure out that Spark associates a task (partition) to each shard in the Elasticsearch index,

There we have our answer, to go faster we should parallelise the process, how to do so ? well by distributing our source index into multiple shards.

By default, Elasticsearch creates an Index with one shard, though,  it is possible to personalised it as below:

```
PUT /index-name
{
     "settings": {
     "index": {
     "number_of_shards": x,  
     "number_of_replicas": xx 
    }
  }
}
```

The number of shards could be higher than the number of Elastic nodes, this is all transparent to Spark.
If the index already exists, try creating a new inex and then use the Elasticsearch [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html)

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Well, in the above issue I was trying to fetch one document. `df.take(1)`. Anyway, after lots of hiccups faced by the team, we ended up phasing out ES in favor of S3. Life was pretty good after that.

Comment: This is what I wanted to highlight https://i.imgur.com/WrGkPoz.png  there is one task that is run on one partition `df. take(1)` won't stop spark from reading all the data and then filtering, on the other hand, if we increase the number of shards, Spark would associate to each one a  partition and so a task which would then run in parallel.

Comment: @ixaxaar I do share your opinion with S3, you have for sure saved yourselves from a lot of unnecessary trouble.